# regex capture text in brackets, omitting optional prefix

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to convert some documents (Wikipedia articles) which contain links with a specific markdown convention.  I want to render these to be reader-friendly without links.  The convention is:

1. Names in double-brackets with of the pattern `[[Article Name|Display Name]]` should be captured ignoring the pipe and preceding text as well as enclosing brackets: 
   `Display Name`.
2. Names in double-brackets of the pattern `[[Article Name]]` should be
   captured without the brackets: `Article Name`.

#### Nested approach (produces desired result)

I know I can handle #1 and #2 in a nested`re.sub()` expression.  For example, this does what I want:

```
s = 'including the [[Royal Danish Academy of Sciences and Letters|Danish Academy of Sciences]], [[Norwegian Academy of Science and Letters|Norwegian Academy of Sciences]], [[Russian Academy of Sciences]], and [[National Academy of Sciences|US National Academy of Sciences]].'

re.sub('\[\[(.*?\|)(.*?)\]\]','\\2',         # case 1
       re.sub('\[\[([^|]+)\]\]','\\1',s)     # case 2
)
# result is correct:
'including the Danish Academy of Sciences, Norwegian Academy of Sciences, Russian Academy of Sciences, and US National Academy of Sciences.'
```

#### Single-pass approach (looking for solution here)

For efficiency and my own improvement, I would like to know whether there is a single-pass approach.

**What I have tried:**  In an optional group 1, I want to greedy-capture everything between `[[` and a `|` (if it exists).  Then in group 2, I want to capture everything else up to the `]]`.  Then I want to return only group 2.

My problem is in making the greedy capture optional:

```
re.sub('\[\[([^|]*\|)?(.*?)\]\]','\\2',s)
# does NOT return the desired result:
'including the Danish Academy of Sciences, Norwegian Academy of Sciences, US National Academy of Sciences.'
# is missing: 'Russian Academy of Sciences, and '
```

Comment: What about [`\[{2}(?:(?:(?!]{2})[^|])+\|)*((?:(?!]{2})[^|])+)]{2}`](https://regex101.com/r/9H34T9/2)?

Comment: I guess that works, if you want to answer go ahead.  I'm interested in whether it can be done without look-aheads or look-backs.  Seems like the nested sub would be faster, but would need to test.

Comment: Have you thought to use a python library that trasform wiki markup - creole - in html markup? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-creole/

Comment: I added an answer. I also added a second regex in the answer that doesn't use lookarounds if you'd prefer to use that, but it's less specific. By that, what I mean is that if a string includes `]` in it, it will stop there (instead of the location of `]]`)

Comment: @Lupanoide I didn't know that was a thing -- thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/9H34T9/2)

```
\[{2}(?:(?:(?!]{2})[^|])+\|)*((?:(?!]{2})[^|])+)]{2}
```

- `\[{2}` Match `[[`
- `(?:(?:(?!]{2})[^|])+\|)*` Matches the following any number of times

  - `(?:(?!]{2})[^|])+` [Tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) matching any character one or more times except `|` or location that matches `]]`
  - `\|` Matches `|` literally
- `((?:(?!]{2})[^|])+)` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `(?:(?!]{2})[^|])+` [Tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) matching any character one or more times except `|` or location that matches `]]`
- `]{2}` Match `]]`

Replacement `\1`

Result:

```
including the Danish Academy of Sciences, Norwegian Academy of Sciences, Russian Academy of Sciences, and US National Academy of Sciences.
```

Another alternative that *may* work for you is the following. It's less specific than the regex above but doesn't include any lookarounds.

```
\[{2}(?:[^]|]+\|)*([^]|]+)]{2}
```

Comment: Yes, the alternative is what I was looking for.  A reason that it works (and my attempt didn't) is that it is also excluding the close brackets as well as the pipe from the optional prefix.  Thanks.